# android:junit report generation

Tags: android, servicetestcase

i want to generate the HTml Report after running the junit testcase in android.Testcase are of type AndroidTestCase ,ProviderTestCase and ServiceTestCase.
and junit report task for this is :-

```
<project name="junitreport-problem" default="test" basedir=".">
<target name="test">
<path id="jarfilepath" >
<fileset dir="lib" >
<include name="*.jar" />
</fileset>
</path>
<junit printsummary="true" >
<classpath refid="jarfilepath" />
<classpath location="./bin" />
<!--type is xml, plain or brief. Best practice is xml-->
<!-- usefile attribute determines whether output should be sent
to a file -->
<formatter type="xml" usefile="true" />
<!-- we can use batchtest instead of test task in ant -->
<!-- <test todir="report" name ="com.android.test.PatientContentManagerTestCase" /> -->
<batchtest todir="report">
<fileset dir="src">
<include name="com.android.test.PatientContentManagerTestCase.java" />
</fileset>
</batchtest>
</junit>
<junitreport todir="report">
<fileset dir="report">
<include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
</fileset>
<report format="frames" todir="report/html"/>
</junitreport>
</target>
</project>
```

This task is generating blank html Report,
please kindly help me in this regard,
candyDhami.

Answer (score 2):

The include tag is the problem:

```
<include name="com.android.test.PatientContentManagerTestCase.java" />
```

The name of the include : `com.android.test.PatientContentManagerTestCase.java` must correspond with the name of your own test class.

Comment: I don't see any difference with his include : <include name="com.android.test.PatientContentManagerTestCase.java" />. So your answer is incorrect IMO.

Comment: I mean, the value named com.android.test.PatientContentManagerTestCase.java is error,it must be correspond with his test class

Comment: Oh I see, maybe you should edit your post and add this information! That would make it way more valuable :) Have a look to our FAQ as well if you haven't! http://stackoverflow.com/faq - I will upvote your answer if you add the info. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The latest Maven Android Plugin will do that for you. See more here

http://www.simpligility.com/2011/09/easier-android-test-reporting-with-maven-and-hudson/